# Vue 3 slot props not reactively changing data in parent

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a slot containing radio buttons in a parent Vue3 component, I'm passing a v-model attribute to these radio buttons and the data model exists in the parent component. However when I change the selected radio button in the slot, the data in the parent component doesn't change.

parent template:

```
<template>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <slot
                :type="type"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

parent vue:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                type: 'standard',
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

slot content:

```
<parent v-slot="slotProps">
    <div class="row">
        <label>
            <span class="required">Type</span>
        </label>
        <label>
            Standard Model
            <input v-model="slotProps.type" type="radio" name="type" value="standard" required/>
        </label>
        <label>
            Touch Model
            <input v-model="slotProps.type" type="radio" name="type" value="touch" required/>
        </label>
        <label>
            Display Model
            <input v-model="slotProps.type" type="radio" name="type" value="display" required/>
        </label>
    </div>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is a good idea and this is also not recommended by the [Vue team](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9726#issuecomment-473710967).
Anyway, if you really need to do it, as stated by [posva](https://github.com/posva) from the Vue team, you can **pass a method instead to change the value** or you can **pass an object and modify a property** (**keep in mind this is not recommended**).
*Here is the **object** way to do it:*
**Parent:**

```
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <slot :myObject="myObject" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      myObject: {
        type: "standard",
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**Slot content:**

```
<parent v-slot="slotProps">
  <div class="row">
    <label>
      <span class="required">Type</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      Standard Model
      <input
        v-model="slotProps.myObject.type"
        type="radio"
        name="type"
        value="standard"
        required
      />
    </label>
    <label>
      Touch Model
      <input
        v-model="slotProps.myObject.type"
        type="radio"
        name="type"
        value="touch"
        required
      />
    </label>
    <label>
      Display Model
      <input
        v-model="slotProps.myObject.type"
        type="radio"
        name="type"
        value="display"
        required
      />
    </label>
  </div>
</parent>
```

*Here is the **method** way to do it:*
**Parent:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <slot :type="type" :onTypeChange="onTypeChange" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      type: "touch",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onTypeChange(event) {
      this.type = event.target.value;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Slot content:**

```
<parent v-slot="slotProps">
  <div class="row">
    <label>
      <span class="required">Type</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      Standard Model
      <input
        v-model="slotProps.type"
        type="radio"
        name="type"
        value="standard"
        required
        @change="slotProps.onTypeChange"
      />
    </label>
    <label>
      Touch Model
      <input
        v-model="slotProps.type"
        type="radio"
        name="type"
        value="touch"
        required
        @change="slotProps.onTypeChange"
      />
    </label>
    <label>
      Display Model
      <input
        v-model="slotProps.type"
        type="radio"
        name="type"
        value="display"
        required
        @change="slotProps.onTypeChange"
      />
    </label>
  </div>
</parent>
```